# What is the purpose and constraints of tf.selectV2

Tags: python, tensorflow

TF documentation simply gives the API without any description beyond, unlike TF.Select which is more descriptive

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/SelectV2 vs. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ops differ in their broadcasting behaviour. You can see their exact implementation in [`tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc), but it may be more useful to read the explanation in [the corresponding TFLite implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/lite/kernels/select.cc#L188-L211):

```cpp
// Select op selects values of 'x' if the corresponding value of 'condition' is
// true or the value of 'y' if false. There are valid condition input sizes:
//
// 1. Either the same shape (in which case the select is elementwise), or
// 2. condition must be Rank 1 and match over the first dimension, or
// 3. condition is scalar
TfLiteRegistration* Register_SELECT() {
  static TfLiteRegistration r = {select::SelectInit, select::SelectFree,
                                 select::SelectPrepare<select::kVersionOne>,
                                 select::SelectEval};
  return &r;
}

// SelectV2 op selects values of 'x' if the corresponding value of 'condition'
// is true or the value of 'y' if false. There are valid condition input sizes:
//
// 1. Either the same shape (in which case the select is elementwise), or
// 2. Broadcastable shapes between 'condition', 'x' and 'y'.
TfLiteRegistration* Register_SELECT_V2() {
  static TfLiteRegistration r = {select::SelectInit, select::SelectFree,
                                 select::SelectPrepare<select::kVersionTwo>,
                                 select::SelectEval};
  return &r;
}
```

These ops are used to implement `tf.where`, which changed its behaviour between TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x. You can refer to the documentation of [the old version of `tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/where) and [the new version of `tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) for further clarification. In the 1.x version it says:

> If both non-None, `x` and `y` must have the same shape. The `condition` tensor must be a scalar if `x` and `y` are scalar. If `x` and `y` are tensors of higher rank, then `condition` must be either a vector with size matching the first dimension of `x`, or must have the same shape as `x`.

Whereas for the 2.x version it is:

> If `x` and `y` are provided (both have non-None values):
>
> [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) will choose an output shape from the shapes of `condition`, `x`, and `y` that all three shapes are [`broadcastable`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) to.